# Elevation Data in form of a database or colored Map

Tags: data, elevation

I am new to the GIS Topic and I hope someone can help me in the following.
I am looking for elevation data for the whole world in the form of

- a database (Latitude; Longitude; Elevation(Level over the Sea))
- in form of a colourmap (Bitmap or SVG) in Mercator Projection without any shadows. It means that each colour represents only its height.

Can you give me a hint where I can find it, or where to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download free data sets from site like:

https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/

Or follow the intro at https://gisgeography.com/free-global-dem-data-sources/

Landsat imagery is free at less resolution, you could try with TerraSar-x price may apply on POI basis https://terrasar-x-archive.terrasar.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://dwtkns.com/srtm/
Very user friendly website to download SRTM data